# How can I split an audacity recording track at regular intervals?

Tags: audacity

It looks like there are a number of ways to split an Audacity audio recording:

- http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Audacity_Tracks_and_Clips
- http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Splitting_recordings_into_separate_tracks
- http://audacity.sourceforge.net/help/faq?s=files&i=split
- http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/features-1.3-c.php

However, I can't find a way to split audacity audio tracks every 3 minutes, for example, without regard to silence.

Is there a way that I can split an Audacity audio track into X number of chunks or every X number of minutes?

Comment: audacity may not be the ideal tool, for really meant for that, i'd guess people just use it to make the recording, it was probably a while till it could even do mp3, till it had the plugin option! Maybe you want to try some other programs. mkvtoolnix can split specifying times to split..you could specify each, don't know if it can easily do every x min  but possibly.

Comment: I just don't want to go through too many decode/encode cycles.  I guess I could write out the audacity track to wav.  It's all just a hassle.  Hopefully someone knows how this is done or a hack for making it happen :-P

Comment: How would writing it to WAV help you? You mean and cut it manually with audacity? BTW re mkvtoolnix I have a suspicion that it's a format designed purely for splitting and joining. so is probably ideal. It has given me some relief when I tried it.

Comment: `wav` format has _no_ compression, so it won't have the associated data loss issues that compression has.  I realize the loss is minimal when going to `mp3`, but I want to minimize distortion. I'll look into `mkvtoolnix` :-)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the solution I'm going with is exporting from Audacity to mp3, and then using [mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php) to split the files.  `mp3splt` does *not* [transcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcoding), so I shouldn't have re-compression [artifacts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_artifact).

Answer (score 3):

In Audacity, select the whole clip then <kbd>Tools > Regular Interval Labels...</kbd>. Here you can specify either the number of intervals to create or the length of each interval. Once you have created the labels, go to <kbd>File > Export > Export Multiple...</kbd> then select <kbd>Split files based on: Labels</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

My solution would be to split using sox or ffmpeg after export...not to try it with audacity.  Automation in a gui tool == not so much...at least for me.

Comment: Mind expanding on how this would work?